# I always received connection reset when trying to execute a test file with TCPDF library. Does this apache error log doing it?

Tags: php, tcpdf

Apache Error Log:

```
[Fri Dec 17 12:10:17.386441 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 12996:tid 612] AH00455: Apache/2.4.51 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1l PHP/8.0.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Dec 17 12:10:17.386441 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 12996:tid 612] AH00456: Apache Lounge VS16 Server built: Oct  7 2021 16:27:02
[Fri Dec 17 12:10:17.386441 2021] [core:notice] [pid 12996:tid 612] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Fri Dec 17 12:10:17.399752 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 12996:tid 612] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 18512
```

I added this:

```
#ThreadStackSize
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
   ThreadStackSize 88888888
</IfModule>
```

at the very end of httpd.conf but the error is still the same. Thanks. I've been stuck here for almost 3 days now, the connection reset thing really is stubborn. I tried several resolve but neither of them solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Add a proper SSL certificate. that should help. currently, you don't have an SSL certificate that doesn't match the domain name you are using.

Comment: Appreciated. I know the risk of having a not properly set SSL Cert but I just want to know whether having such error would cease the TCPDF library to properly load up without any connection reset error? I reviewed the apache error logs and that SSL Cert thingy have been a problem for almost a year or two already but this is the only time I got stuck with the connection reset error while using TCPDF library.

Comment: without a proper SSL certificate, it won't work... cause of security reasons.          1) a lot of malicious sites don't have a proper SSL certificate. this is the main reason why certain libraries don't accept without a proper certificate.                                        it could also be a bug. check with the developer if it Is a bug or you can refer to the documentation

Comment: I have fixed the SSL CERT issue already. However, it doesn't fix the problem. Thank you.

Comment: then please delete this post(to close it)

Comment: No. I'll just leave it here. I have fixed the SSL Cert issue yet it did not resolve the main problem. Thank you.

Comment: I can use TCPDF normally for both http and https. Is you TCPDF file contains unlimited loop code?

Comment: Hi Heroic Project! is your issue resolved?